# Apache Calcite SQL parser not able to parse the SQL query with column or column alias having a number

Tags: apache-calcite, sql-parser

Example query:
`SELECT empid as 3_e FROM EMP`;

Error:

```
Exception: org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Encountered "3" at line 1, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    <QUOTED_STRING> ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BIG_QUERY_BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <HYPHENATED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
```

If I update the query to remove digit from the column alias the query is getting parsed

Updated query - SELECT empid as e FROM EMP

Does calcite support digits in the column or column alias name?